# What should be the ideal power of a trademill motor for 70 kg man?

Tags: gym

I want to create a trdemill for home purpose. My weight is around 70kg. So what should be the ideal power of motor to be used?

Any video tutorial for making trademill will also help considering low cost.

Thanks !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this board isn't about creating ones own gym equipment.

Comment: well it's about filness, where else should I ask this question, any suggestion ?

Comment: This board is about question that directly regard working out, this website isn't for "what brand makes good running shoes" or "what gym do you enjoy going too". You're asking about the power of a motor for a treadmill and tutorials about making a treadmill. That is not working out, that is building a treadmill.

Comment: You're better off consulting a DIY forum for technical questions like this. The Help Center lists what kind of questions are considered on-topic for this board: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help - Essentially, since this forum is meant for the actual exercise aspect of fitness, we just don't have the knowledge to answer your question, unless someone coincidentally happens to also be a DIY-type person. :)